# PHP-CGI is not loading extensions

Tags: php, cgi

I have a local server running PHP-GCI 5.3.0, but when I run `phpinfo()` it shows me normal information, but extensions.

There are nothing about extensions, and I'm using its normal `ext` folder.

Could this be related to my folder having spaces? (i.e. this is my `php.ini` `C:\Arquivos de programas\Winco\Winconnection4\php.ini`)

I need to do something different to load extensions while using CGI?

This is my `php.ini`:

> [PHP]
>   zend_extension="ext/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.3-vc6.dll"
>   register_globals=Off
>   safe_mode = on
>   cgi.force_redirect = Off
>   extension_dir="ext"
>   session.bug_compat_warn=Off;
>
> `#`ATIVANDO A COMPACTAÇÃO DA PAGINA
>   `#`zlib.output_compression = On
>
> error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
>
> display_errors = on
>
> extension=php_sqlite3.dll

Answer (score 1):

Here a a couple of pointers ; with a bit of luck, one of those might be helpful :

- first of all, are you sure you are editing the right php.ini file ? there could be several of those on your computer (for instance, one in the windows/system32 directory ; and another one in the PHP installation directory) ; `phpinfo()` says in the output which php.ini file is loaded ; make sure you are modifying the right one ;-)
- When using `zend_extension` to load a Zend Extension, you should use an absolute path ; see [Xdebug - Installation](http://xdebug.org/docs/install)
- what about using an absolute path for `extension_dir` ?
- If I rememeber correctly, you should use ";" not "#" for comments in .ini files

If you try launching PHP via the command line, do you get any error ? Same in Apache's log file ?

Hoping one of those will help...